# scipy.brute ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: python, python-2.7, scipy, maximize

I have a problem with scipy.brute, I set the maximization in this way

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import brute
from scipy.optimize import fmin
from scipy.stats import norm 

lambmarket=np.array([1.1076, 0.0615, 0.15238, 0.16265, 0.1761301, 0.193762, 0.0778772, 0.079162, 0.07505194, 0.071973])
xnew = np.array([0.5, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 7.0, 10.0, 20.0, 30.0])

def optimization(key):
    if key=='inc':
         ranges=slice(0,2,0.2), slice(0.001,2.998,0.5)
         finalB =brute(incmse, ranges, full_output=True,finish=None, disp=True)
         finalA=fmin(incmse, finalB[0], xtol=0.001, ftol=0.001, maxiter=500, maxfun=500)

    return finalA
```

where

```
def incmse(*p):

    v, sigma =p[0]
    print v,sigma

    msqdiff=[(( lambmarket[t]  - s_t(0.,xnew[t], v, 0.003, sigma) )**2)  for t in range(0,len(xnew))]

    print sum(msqdiff)
    return msqdiff


def s_t(t,T,v,r,sigma):
    m=r-0.5*sigma**2
    gamma=1+2*m/(sigma**2)
    nu=m+sigma**2
    delta=m-gamma*sigma**2
    beta=-m*gamma+(gamma**2)*(sigma**2)/2
    s = lambda t,T,v: norm.cdf((-v-m*(T-t))/(sigma*np.sqrt(T-t))) - np.exp(v+r*(T-t)) * norm.cdf((-v-nu*(T-t))/(sigma*np.sqrt(T-t))) \
        + np.exp(( 1-gamma )*v)/gamma * norm.cdf((m*(T-t)-v)/(sigma*np.sqrt(T-t))) \
        - np.exp(v+(T-t)*beta)/gamma * norm.cdf((delta*(T-t)-v)/(sigma* np.sqrt(T-t)))

    lamb = ((1/0.01) * (s(t,T+0.01,v)-s(t,T,v)))/(1-s(t,T,v))


    return lamb
```

It can be executed by

```
 optimization('inc')
```

(lambmarket and xnew are global)
from the prints I know that the error comes after all the brute force iterations have finished...is there someone that can explain me?

(I looked for similar threads and tried to solve by myself but I still can't understand what the problem is)

Full error output

```
param=optimization(key)
File "/home/myway/calibration.py", line 129, in optimization
finalB =brute(incmse, ranges, full_output=True,finish=None, disp=True)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py", line 2542, in brute
Jout = vecfunc(*grid)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 1573, in __call__
return self._vectorize_call(func=func, args=vargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line  1643, in _vectorize_call
copy=False, subok=True, dtype=otypes[0])
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Comment: Please transform this into a [mcve]. We don't know what `lambmarket` is for instance.

Comment: edited, it should be compliant now

Comment: There are still undefined variables. (e.g. `xnew`, `r`)

Comment: I'm sorry, as you may understand this code is a part of a much larger project...by the way, now it should run (I just tried)

Comment: `return msqdiff` should be `return sum(msqdiff)`, right? Otherwise you would return a vector.

Comment: oh my god, yes sure...I have been trying for hours without understanding what was going on! Sorry for this stupid question and many many thanks!

Comment: Glad you solved it. You may want to post an answer explaining the problem + the solution. This error is rather difficult to figure out, when you see it the first time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by cel, the problem is simply I was (unintendly) returning a vector instead of a single value, the function *incmse* must be modified as follows

```
def incmse(*p):

     v, sigma =p[0]
     print v,sigma

     msqdiff=[(( lambmarket[t]  - s_t(0.,xnew[t], v, 0.003, sigma) )**2)  for t in range(0,len(xnew))]

     print sum(msqdiff)
     return sum(msqdiff)
```

Now a single value is passed to scipy.optimize.brute as required for it to work.